# How to get the substring from between two [ ] braces in a string in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

My string looks like this  `street no [12]`

I need to extract the `12` alone from the string.

How do I get the substring between two `[` `]`  in javascript or jquery?

find the substring between first matching [] brackets

Comment: You can use regex to do this: `/\[(\d+)\]/`: https://regex101.com/r/Cve6sI/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noted that your requirements changed in a comment below the previous answer, to fix that issue you can change the regex adding `?` so it will capture the least possible matches.

```js
const myString = "street no [12][22]"
const match = myString.match(/\[(.+?)\]/);
const myNumber = match && match[1];
console.log(myNumber);
```

Or, you can just capture digits if that works better for your needs

```js
const myString = "street no [12][22]"
const match = myString.match(/\[(\d+)\]/);
const myNumber = match && match[1];
console.log(myNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks , it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```js
const myString = "street no [12]"
const match = myString.match(/\[(.+)\]/);
const myNumber = match && match[1];
console.log(myNumber);
```

Comment: it returns 12[22  for the string like 'stree number [12] [22] , i need the output to be 12 alone